# How to update table with subselect

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to join the output from the subselect with the fields in the update table. But can't get it right using MySQL.

Any idea how to do it correctly?

```
update INSTRUMENTDAILYINFO info 
set 
    info.vWap = (SELECT 
            t1.vWap
        FROM
            INSTRUMENTDAY t1
                JOIN
            (SELECT 
                Date(tradedate) date_date,
                    stockName,
                    min(tradedate) min_date
            FROM
                INSTRUMENTDAY
            GROUP BY date_date , stockName) t2 ON t1.tradedate = t2.min_date
                AND t1.stockName = t2.stockName
        order by t1.tradedate , t1.stockName asc)
where
    t1.tradeDate = info.tradeDate
        and t1.stockName = info.stockName

SELECT
`INSTRUMENTDAILYINFO`.`ID`,
`INSTRUMENTDAILYINFO`.`CLOSEPRICE`,
`INSTRUMENTDAILYINFO`.`HIGHVALUE`,
`INSTRUMENTDAILYINFO`.`LOWVALUE`,
`INSTRUMENTDAILYINFO`.`STARTPRICE`,
`INSTRUMENTDAILYINFO`.`STOCKNAME`,
`INSTRUMENTDAILYINFO`.`TRADEDATE`
FROM `INSTRUMENTDAILYINFO`;

SELECT
`INSTRUMENTDAY`.`ID`,
`INSTRUMENTDAY`.`STOCKNAME`,
`INSTRUMENTDAY`.`TRADEDATE`,
`INSTRUMENTDAY`.`VWAP`
FROM `SimpleGrowth`.`INSTRUMENTDAY`;
```

Comment: Could you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE INSTRUMENTDAILYINFO info 
JOIN
(SELECT t1.vWap,t1.tradedate as tradedate,t2.stockName as stockName 
  FROM INSTRUMENTDAY t1
             JOIN
            (SELECT 
                Date(tradedate) date_date,
                    stockName,
                    min(tradedate) min_date
            FROM
                INSTRUMENTDAY
            GROUP BY date_date , stockName) t2 ON t1.tradedate = t2.min_date
                AND t1.stockName = t2.stockName
            ORDER BY t1.tradedate , t1.stockName asc)x
ON
     x.tradeDate = info.tradeDate
AND x.stockName = info.stockName
SET  info.vWap= x.vWap
```

Something like this if you have a joining column between the main table and the x sub query.

Comment: What does someCommonColumn refer to tradeDate and stockName ? I am getting 0 rows updated while running the query.

Comment: @user2130951 show tables structure,INSTRUMENTDAILYINFO and INSTRUMENTDAY - the foreign key column linking the 2 shoud be used there.

Comment: Excellent! Saving this query. Just adding to this since one table field is Timestamp and the other date the ON works if DATE(x.tradeDate) = info.tradeDate